# Accessing Rails Helper files from models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, models, helper

I am trying to validate the input of a state field using:

```
include ActionView::Helpers
class Credentials < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :license_number, ...:address_zip_code,

    ...

    validates :license_number,  presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
    ...
    validates_inclusion_of :current_practice_address_state, :in => state_list

end
```

The variable state_list is an array described in helpers/credentials_helper.rb

Testing the model I run into undefined local variable error

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/credentials_spec.rb
in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `state_list' for #<Class:0x007f86a1844250> (NameError)
```

The helper class looks like:

```
 module CredentialsHelper
        state_list = %w(AL AK...WY)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `include` has to be inside the class:

```
class Credentials < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers
  ...
end
```

Comment: Okay thanks for that (doh!) but the errors persist.  `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `state_list' for #<Class:0x007fb71d960448> (NameError)`

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to `extend` not `include`. See: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/ Change `include ActionView::Helpers` to `extend ActionView::Helpers`.